# Prove a linear combination of a convex set is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ , and  suppose $T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m $  is any linear transformation. Prove that the set $\,\{T(x)\,|\,x \in S \}$ is also convex.

$\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers and $x$ is a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Say, $y_1, y_2 \in T(S)$. So, we can write them as, $y_1=T(x_1), \ y_2=T(x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2 \in S$.

$$ty_1+(1-t)y_2 \text{ where } t\in [0,1]$$
$$=tT(x_1)+(1-t)T(x_1)$$
$$=T(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \in T(S) \text{ because }tx_1+(1-t)x_2 \in S$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Since $T$ is linear $T(tx+(1-t)y)=tT(x)+(1-t)T(y)$ where $t\in [0,1]$ and $x,y\in S$

Answer (score 0):

Also note that $T^{-1}(S)$ is convex, since taking $x_1,x_2\in T^{-1}(S)$ it follows that $T(x_1),T(x_2)\in S$ and thus $tT(x_1)+(1-t)T(x_2)\in S$, but $tT(x_1)+(1-t)T(x_2)=T(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)$, thereby $tx_1+(1-t)x_2\in T^{-1}(S)$